# MySQL Query with a status check from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

There are three tables involved with this query.

Table1:

| app_id | app_name | menu_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | BigApp | 1 |
| 2 | smallApp | 2 |
| 3 | theApp | 2 |

Table2:

| menu_id | menu_title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | menu1 |
| 2 | menu2 |

Table3:

| user_id | app_id_list |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
| 2 | 1,3,5 |

So I want to grab the **app_name**, **menu_title** and then add another column (**user_status**, where would 1=on, 0=off) to verify that the **app_id** shows up in the **app_id_list** for a given user. The results for **user_id = 2** would be:

| app_name | menu_title | user_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BigApp | menu1 | 1 |
| smallApp | menu2 | 0 |
| theApp | menu2 | 1 |

The SQL statement I've got so far is:

```
SELECT Table1.app_name, t2.menu_title
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON (t2.menu_id = Table1.menu_id)
```

Not sure how to find the last column of data from Table3. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the following discussion:

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

I have solved this issue by creating and expanding the Table3 where each value that was in the **app_id_list** now has its own row. Faster and can just link up with another JOIN.